# geom_treemap() not coloring the correct borders of subgroups

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap

My dataset trial is

```
variable   value    SubGroup1
  Total     6.44        A
 Total-Crop 4.54        A
```

I need a treemap like below, specifically the second figure where Total-Crop is an actual subset of Total (4.54<6.54) (Fig A is to give an idea of the total size of the block i.e. 6.44).

[image]

With my ggplot treemap code below, my plot is such that Total-Crop is not a subset of Total, even though I have specified SubGroup. See image below where the boxes are adjoining each other and are almost the same size since 4.54 is close to 6.44.

```
plot<-ggplot(trial, aes(area = value, label=variable, fill=variable, subgroup= SubGroup1)) +
geom_treemap() + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens") +
geom_treemap_subgroup_border(colour="red", size=3)+
geom_treemap_text (color="black", place="center",reflow=TRUE) + guides(fill=FALSE)+ theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Do I need to change my dataframe such that Total is 6.44-4.54~2.5? How do I modify the treemap() code with subgroup to get the second fig of my first panel?